# ¿Por qué cuando selecciono uno de los botones que tengo creados para saber su contenido, me devuelve siempre el contenido del último?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

> Intento crear un table layout dinámico, con botónes dinámicos con todo el abecedario. Con el código que tengo lo crea bien, pero cuando selecciono cualquier botón para ver su contenido me devuelve siempre el contenido del último botón, osea la Z. Si pudierais decirme donde esta el error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
  //Método de creación de btotones
private void crearbt() {
    String letras[] = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "Ñ", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    tbl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabla);
    //Este for para el número de rows que quiero
    for (int d = 0; d < 4; d++) {
        TableRow tbr = new TableRow(this);
        tbr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        //Número de botones que se crearan en cada row
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            bt = new Button(this);
            bt.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(86, 86));
            bt.setId(i+1);
            bt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#26ff00"));
            bt.setText(letras[idbt]);
            bt.setTextSize(20);
            bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boton: " + bt.getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
            idbt++;
            tbr.addView(bt);

           if (idbt == 27){
                break;

            }
        }
        tbl.addView(tbr);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pon Button bt = new Button(this); dentro del for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agrega este código en `setOnClickListener`.

```
String btn = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
```

Quedaría de esta forma:

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        String btn = ((Button)v).getText().toString();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boton: " +btn, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Muchas gracias me funcionó tu método.

Comment: Me da gusto  que te sirviera, puedes marcar cualquiera de las dos respuestas que se te brindo como aceptada, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es usar el Tag para identificarlo, puedes asignar esta propiedad mediante el método [setTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setTag(java.lang.Object)) de la vista.

De la misma forma que asignas el id, puedes asignar el valor de la etiqueta (tag) de esta forma, pero te aconsejo uses los valores desde el indice 0:

```
 bt.setId(i+1);//asigna id.

 bt.setTag(i);// valor tag.
```

el indice del botón se guardara (como String) y al obtenerlo y convertirlo a entero podrás usarlo como indice del array para diferenciar cual es la vista que estas dando clic :

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boton: " + letras[Integer.parseInt(bt.getTag().toString())], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
```

Otra opción es obteniendo la instancia del botón y el texto que agregaste previamente mediante `bt.setText(letras[idbt])` :

```
bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Boton: " + ((Button)v).getText().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias también me resultó de gran ayuda tu método.

Comment: Hola @JabelÁlvarezAcosta en realidad son 2 opciones que puedes usar, saludos!